# ¿como encontrar palabras entre varios caracteres y convertir a números?

Tags: java, main

Tengo un código en java que debería realizar lo siguiente en una lista de cadenas, cada cadena se puede interpretar como un número utilizando el primer dígito encontrado como el dígito de las decenas y el último como el dígito de las unidades, devolviendo la suma de todos los números. de la tabla de calibración si el primer o el ultimo digito encontrado es un numero entonces debería tomar esos valores en este momento no estoy logrando corregir mi código ya que no obtengo los resultados esperados, alguien podría ayudarme por favor este es mi código

```java
package test2;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class Solution {

    public int calibration(String[] table) {

        int sum = 0;

        for (String str : table) {

            int number = extractNumber(str);

            sum += number;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private int extractNumber(String str) {

        // Utilizamos una expresión regular para encontrar los dígitos en la cadena
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        // Sumamos todos los números encontrados en la cadena

        int sum = 0;

        while (matcher.find()) {

            sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Ejemplo de uso
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        String[] calibrations = {"two1nine", "eightwothree", "abcone2threexyz", "xtwone3four", "4nineeightseven2", "zoneight234", "7pqrstsixteen"};

        int result = solution.calibration(calibrations);

        System.out.println("Output: " + result);

    }
}
```

si ejecuto esos valores debería entresacar los valores la entrada se puede convertir a [29, 83, 13, 24, 42, 14, 76], sumando los números obtendrá el resultado, 281, pero el resultado que ahora arroja al ejecutar es 253

Comment: ¿Conoces la clase `Scanner`? Divide la entrada en tokens delimitados por espacios en blanco. También posee diferentes funciones para extraerlos o que brindan información sobre ellos. Si tienes que crear tu propia implementación, es buena idea inspirarse en la que ya existe. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: no estas detallando bien el requerimiento de tu codigo, si empieza con numero y termina en numero se considerara como decena y unidad respecitvamente ?.. pero si la cadena inicia en texto se buscara el valor de ese texto y se interpretara el valor como numero .una vez hecho eso aplicara lo de unidad y decena?

Comment: por ejemplo en este caso 4nineeightseven2 el resultado debe ser 42, y para este otro caso zoneight234 el resultado es 14, sin embargo para los caracteres como este eightwothree tomara la primera y la ultima palabra como un numero eightwothree = 83, si el carácter comienza o termina con un valor numérico entonces debe tomar ese dato como dígitos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Buenas...*

Es evidente que la expresion regular que usas no hace nada con los *substrings* que debe operar y tratar de convertir a un respectivo valor numerico.
Especialmente el caso concreto de '*eightwothree*' lo que se me ocurre es buscar cada *substring* que sea valido en una serie ya preestablecida y entonces sí pasarlo a su equivalencia, eso sí teniendo en cuenta su ubicacion dentro de todo el *string*.

Me explico con codigo lo mejor que pueda, en donde habra una lista para guardar unos indices ***(importantes para saber cual substring valido está primero o mas a la izq. y cual está ultimo o mas a la derecha)*** y un mapa de *hash* para guardar pares de éste indice y su cadena valida para conversion:

```
private void calibration(String[]arr) {
  //los valores a buscar en cada string del array entrante
  String[]v={"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine",
             "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
  List<Integer>l=new ArrayList<>();//aqui estaran unos indices
  Map<Integer,String>map=new HashMap<>();//aqui indice y string valido
  int s=0;//para la suma

  //iteracion para buscar cada string valido en el array entrante
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<v.length;j++) {
      Pattern p=Pattern.compile(v[j]);
      Matcher m=p.matcher(arr[i]);
      if(m.find()) {
        //guarda el indice donde inicia el substring valido
        l.add(m.start());
        //hashmap con ese indice y su substring valido
        map.put(m.start(),arr[i].substring(m.start(),m.end()));
      }
    }

    //ordena la lista. facilita traer el primer y 
    //ultimo valor validos (0, y n-1)
    Collections.sort(l);
    
    //println de referencia nada mas
    System.out.println(map.get(l.get(0))+" "+map.get(l.get(l.size()-1)));
    
    //produce la suma pasando los substring validos en el hashmap
    s+=sum(map.get(l.get(0)),map.get(l.get(l.size()-1)));        
    
    //se vacian el hashmap y la lista
    map.remove(l.get(0)); map.remove(l.get(l.size()-1));
    l.removeAll(l);
  }
  System.out.println("OUTPUT: "+s);
}
```

Adicionalmente la parte que realiza la conversion y posterior suma:

```
private int sum(String str1,String str2) {
  return parser(str1)*10 + parser(str2);
}

private int parser(String s) {
  switch(s) {
    case "zero":   return 0;
    case "one":    return 1;
    case "two":    return 2;
    case "three":  return 3;
    case "four":   return 4;
    case "five":   return 5;
    case "six":    return 6;
    case "seven":  return 7;
    case "eight":  return 8;
    case "nine":   return 9;
    default:       return Integer.parseInt(s);
  }
}
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
  //29, 83, 13, 24, 42, 14, 76 expected: 281
  String[]a={"two1nine","eightwothree","abcone2threexyz","xtwone3four",
             "4nineeightseven2","zoneight234","7pqrstsixteen"};
  new Solution().calibration(a);
}
```

salida:

```
two nine
eight three
one three
two four
4 2
one 4
7 six
OUTPUT: 281
```

***Edit:***

En el caso `eightwothree` este programa busca secuencialmente a traves del array predefinido, primero encontrará `two` (*indice 4 en el string*) luego `three` (*indice 7 en el string*)y por ultimo `eight` (*indice 0 en el string*), ese no es el orden correcto, por eso para determinar el orden verdadero se guarda el indice de ocurrencia del substring en la lista `l.add(m.start())`. primero va a contener `[4,7,0]` y despues de ordenada será `[0,4,7]`, buscamos el primer y ultimo indice en el *hashmap*; `0` traerá `eight` y `7` traerá `three`